# What roles are considered power roles?

Tags: werewolv.es

And what do you call a role such as the Lycan that's neither a vanilla nor a power role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is somewhat subjective as there is no clear-cut well-defined answer as to which roles are "power" roles and which are not, different people will have different answers.

Some definitions could be "Provides some kind of service/intel to the village" or "Has an active/non-passive night-time ability" or "Not a plain villager".

Comment: If you feel this is too subjective, you should flag it for closure for being primarily opinion based.  I don't know the game at all, so it would be hard for me to say so.